# Why can't my body draw a tiny piece of paper despite gravitation pull it exerts on the piece of paper?

Tags: gravity

We observe in static electricity experiments that a comb rubbed on dry hair lifts tiny pieces of paper.This is due to the attraction force exerted by the charge collecting on the surface of the comb on the opposite charges collecting on the hair.This is a very small amount of force.But our body is always exerting gravitational force on all objects around it.Still it cannot draw such tiny pieces of papers.Why?

Comment: The gravitational force between your body and the paper is approximately $F = GMm/r^2$, where $M$ is your mass, $m$ is the mass of the paper, $r$ is the distance between your centre of mass and the paper and $G$ is the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant). Use this to calculate the force and you'll see why you can't lift the paper due to gravitation alone.

Comment: As John said, the Gravitational constant $G$ is of the order of magnitude $10^{-11}$. As human beings are not Giants with 1000s of tonnes as their mass, lifting even light objects with their gravity is impractical.

Comment: As said, in order to manipulate objects with our gravity alone, we'd need an awful amount of weight, Jennie Craig would have a fit...

Comment: Very enlightening reply for me.Thanks to John and imakesmalltalk.This will help me replying my son.Now, what is the nature of force and what  formula is applicable in case of the lifting of the pieces of paper by the comb?

Comment: it is an electric force, the attraction between to individual charges is pretty similar to that of gravitational attraction. Just replace the masses by  the charges and G by k, the Coulomb constant.

Comment: The electrostatic force is described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law). The only trouble is that there's no easy way to estimate what the charge density on the comb is.

Comment: @JohnRennie can the charge density be calculated from known factors such as the magnitude of force on the paper?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot observe things moving towards due to your gravitational attraction is because compared to the other three fundamental forces, gravity is the weakest! The strength of the electromagnetic force is 10³⁶ more than gravity. The apparent lack of gravity between you and the paper is also due to innumerable forces such as air pressure, friction, the gravity of the earth.etc. In a completely isolated friction-less gravity free system you and the paper would move towards each other albeit at a very slow rate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a mass of $64kg$ and a small bit of paper has a mass of $1g$ Let's also assume that you curl up into a ball and hover above the paper bits (you must be David Blaine) such that your center of mass is $1m$ above the paper. The gravitational force that your entire body exerts on that small bit of paper is then:
$$F_{you}=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}=\frac{G(64kg)(0.001kg)}{(1m)^2}=4.27\times10^{-12}N$$

The force of gravity that Earth uses to keep that paper in place is:
$$F_{Earth}=\frac{G(5.97\times10^{24}kg)(0.001kg)}{(6371000m)^2}=9.81\times10^{-3}N$$
So Earth is keeping the paper from moving toward you. But what if you were in space with nothing else keeping the paper from moving toward you? That $4.27\times10^{-12}N$ applied to the $1g$ paper bit means it will accelerate towards you at $4.27\times10^{-9}m/s^2$. Granted, that value will increase as the paper moves closer to you; by the time it reaches half a meter from you, it's accelerating four times that much. But even at that rate, it would take $t=\sqrt{2d/a}=\sqrt{2(0.5m)/(1.71\times10^{-8}m/s^2)}=2.12h$ for that paper bit to cover half a meter. Compare that to the $0.32s$ for Earth to make it fall half a meter. Not only that, but with such a weak force, friction is more than enough to keep that paper bit where it is on the table.

The reason electrostatics can move the paper is that electrostatic forces are much stronger than gravity. As mentioned, the electromagnetic force is $10^{36}$ times stronger than gravity, so it's easy to overcome gravity with even a small static charge.